# Get List of bean types from application context

Tags: java, spring

I'm interested in getting a list of beans from the Spring `ApplicationContext`.  In particular, these are `Ordered` beans

```
 @Component
  @Order(value=2)
```

And I'm in some legacy code that is not Spring enabled, so I've manufactured a method to get the `ApplicationContext`.  For spring beans, I know I can do something like:

```
@Bean
public SomeType someType(List<OtherType> otherTypes) {
    SomeType someType = new SomeType(otherTypes);
    return someType;
}
```

But the `ApplicationContext` only provides a method `getBeansOfType` which returns an unordered map.  I've tried `getBeanNames(type)` but that also returns things unordered.

The only thing I can think of is to create a dummy class that just contains the List, create a bean for that dummy class and retrieve the ordered list:

```
public class DumbOtherTypeCollection {
    private final List<OtherType) otherTypes;
    public DumbOtherTypeCollection(List<OtherType) otherTypes) {
        this.otherTypes = otherTypes;
    }

    List<OtherType> getOrderedOtherTypes() { return otherTypes; }
}

@Bean 
DumbOtherTypeCollection wasteOfTimeReally(List<OtherType otherTypes) {
    return new DumbOtherTypeCollection(otherTypes);
}

....

applicationContext.getBean(DumbOtherTypeCollection.class).getOrderedOtherTypes();
```

Just wish I could do better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spring can autowire all beans of a type into  list. In addition to this if your beans are annotated with the `@Ordered` or if the beans implement the `Ordered` interface, then this list will have all the beans ordered.(Spring [reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation))

`@Autowired` docs:

> In case of a Collection or Map dependency type, the container will autowire all beans matching the declared value type.

```
@Autowired
List<MyType> beans;
```

**EDIT: Ordering using the built-in OrderComparator**

For your external context call, in order to have your beans prioritized by their order you could take advandate of the built-in comparator:

```
org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationAwareOrderComparator(new ArrayList(applicationContext.getBeansOfType(...).values()));
```

Or

```
Collections.sort((List<Object>)applicationContext.getBeansOfType(...).values(),org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationAwareOrderComparator.INSTANCE);
```

Comment: Yep, the problem is that I can't turn the legacy class into a spring controlled bean.

Comment: Compile error.. sort() takes a List, not a Map, which is what getBeansOfType returns.  I'll poke deeper into this OrderComparator though, thanks!

Comment: Hey Alex, thanks for all the help.  I did something along those lines... interestingly, they still came in out of order.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. Theres also `AnnotationAwareOrderComparator` which takes into account the `Order` annotation. The OrderComparator searches for the oredering value only in the `Ordered` interface. Give it another shot :D